# How can I write a function like getc() to read one bit at a time?

Tags: c

I have a function that reads each bit in an unsigned long long and stores the value in an array, and now I want to convert this function into one that returns the next bit in the number and leave handling the data to the caller.

Ideally, it would work similar to getc() where I can do something like:

```
int n;
while((n = getbit()) != NULL)
    ...
```

I know a static index variable is an option, but that isn't very elegant. Is there a more practical way to do this?

Comment: `getc` uses global `stdin` variable, too. If that's not okay with you, check out `fgetc` which takes the file is as parameter instead.

Comment: Also, `NULL` is 0, which is a valid bit value. You may want to return EOF (-1) instead.

Comment: How do you intent to provide the value of the `unsigned long long` to your function? Do you want to read data from a file/`stdin` like `getc` does?

Comment: I have updated the question, rephrasing the title to make it less subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much like a `FILE` structure wraps up various state around input, such as buffering, error states *etc*, you can wrap up the required state for extracting bits with a simple struct:

```
// Struct used to manage reading bits from a file
struct bitstream
{
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned char ch;     // current char
    unsigned char mask;   // next bit mask
    unsigned char mask0;  // first bit mask
};
```

This maintains the `FILE` being read from, keeps track of the last character read from that file, and manages a bit mask that will select one bit at a time. Because different applications may require a specific [bit order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) (LSB->MSB or MSB->LSB), one extra member `mask0` is used for that. You'll see how this is used in a moment.

First, you'll want a function to set up this struct, ready for action. Let's have two functions, which explicitly choose the desired bit ordering:

```
// Initialize a bitstream where bit ordering is LSB -> MSB
void bitstream_init_lsb(struct bitstream* bs, FILE *fp)
{
    struct bitstream bs_init = { fp };
    bs_init.mask0 = 1u;
    *bs = bs_init;
}

// Initialize a bitstream where bit ordering is MSB -> LSB
void bitstream_init_msb(struct bitstream* bs, FILE *fp)
{
    struct bitstream bs_init = { fp };
    bs_init.mask0 = 1u << (CHAR_BIT - 1);
    *bs = bs_init;
}
```

Note the difference in `mask0` in these two functions. For LSB-priority, `mask0` is the lowest-order bit. For MSB-priority, `mask0` is the highest-order bit. In both cases, `ch` and `mask` are zero-initialized. We can rely on a zero value for `mask` to indicate that all bits have been read out of `ch`, and that we must read the next byte from the file.

The way this will work is that every time you read a bit, you shift the mask in the appropriate direction (left or right, depending on selected ordering). In either case, the mask will become zero again when the bit is shifted beyond its storage capabilities. You then know that it's time to read the next byte.

Note that the above logic explicitly relies on `mask` being an `unsigned char` type. That's important.

```
// Get next bit (0 or 1) from bitstream, or EOF
int bitstream_get(struct bitstream *bs)
{
    // Get next character when next bit is zero
    if (bs->mask == 0) {
        int ch = fgetc(bs->fp);
        if (ch == EOF) {
            return EOF;
        }
        bs->ch = (unsigned char) ch;
        bs->mask = bs->mask0;
    }

    // Get next bit
    int result = (bs->ch & bs->mask) ? 1 : 0;
    if (bs->mask0 == 1u) {
        bs->mask <<= 1;
    } else {
        bs->mask >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks to [chux - Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359) for their suggested [improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72886334/1553090) to my original answer. The above is a revision, incorporating those changes and also implementing bit ordering explicitly.

To use this, you would simply initialize with a valid `FILE*` and then do a read loop just the same as you would with `fgetc`:

```
int bit;
struct bitstream bs;

bitstream_init_msb(&bs, stdin);

while (EOF != (bit = bitstream_get(&bs)))
{
    // ...
}
```

Here is a live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/KdEMoTavh

Comment: You might mention the [Bit Numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) aspect: there are different ways to enumerate the bits: from the most significant to the least significant as you have implemented, but also from the least significant to the most significant, which may be more consistent in some applications.

Comment: I did mention the conscious decision to choose one or the other. The approach could be adapted so that it supports both, and that's chosen when initializing the struct.

Comment: @chqrlie I have updated the answer to support left-to-right and right-to-left orderings, and incorporated chux's fixes for EOF handling.

Answer (score 2):

Like [@paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72878643/2410359)'s good answer but with alternative (IMO better) EOF handling.

```
struct bitstream {
  FILE *fp;
  unsigned char ch;    // current char
  unsigned char mask;  // next bit mask
};

int bitstream_get(struct bitstream *bs) {
  // Get next character when next bit is zero
  if (bs->mask == 0) {
    int ch = fgetc(bs->fp);
    if (ch == EOF) {
      return EOF;
    }
    bs->ch = (unsigned char) ch;
    bs->mask = 1u << (CHAR_BIT - 1);
  }

  // Get next bit
  int result = (bs->ch & bs->mask) ? 1 : 0;
  bs->mask >>= 1;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that's a good point. I was dumbly figuring that once EOF is hit, that's the end. But of course, more characters can arrive if the file is being appended from elsewhere, so always calling `fgetc` is the correct thing to do.

Comment: @paddy True - a subsequent call may occur.  `EOF` due to end-of-file is locked - keeps happening until re-set.   `EOF` due to error might not repeat.  Best not to out think the state of `bs->fp`.

Comment: If you don't mind, I will revise my answer to incorporate your changes. I can also address the suggestion about bit ordering, which is more cleanly handled by your modification to the type of `mask`.

Comment: @paddy [be my guest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afzmwAKUppU).

Comment: @paddy (only for the pedantic) Should `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` (some graphics process of years ago), code could use `if (ch == EOF)` --> `if (ch == EOF && (feof(bs->fp) || ferror(bs->fp))` to detect a true `EOF` and the `u` in `1u << (CHAR_BIT - 1)` becomes useful to not shift into the sign bit.

Comment: That does sound rather pedantic, and I like it! But not quite enough to make those changes though. ;)

Comment: @paddy Agree'd.